# Edit All Git Commit Messages to Remove Line

Tags: git, svn, commit

I have a Git repository that was converted from Subversion with [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn). I do not have the original Subversion repo anymore and all of the commit messages have a line like this:

```
git-svn-id: file:///home/jordan/Development/wxSVG/wxsvg-svn/trunk@618 918b0bbe-f86e-4b6f-834e-cb0f658702cb
```

I want to edit all the commit messages to get rid of this line. I am aware that my Git history will be rewritten and I am okay with that. Manually editing each commit will take a very long time and I would like to know if there is a way to automate this.

I am on a Windows system, but am using a Unix-like shell so Unix/Linux commands are okay. I'm guessing I will need to use the `sed` command somehow to modify the commit messages, but I have no idea how I would do this.

When I run the `git rebase -i <commit-id>` command my editor opens & I have to change all `pick` values to `reword`. Then I will need to remove the line starting with `git-svn-id` when the editor opens for each commit.

Is this somehow possible?

**Edit:** I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233988/automatically-reword-all-rebased-commits), so my question might be considered a duplicate. I am trying out the suggestions right now and have already found the answer to automatically change "pick" to "reword".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233988/automatically-reword-all-rebased-commits) helped me to find a solution:

The first part of my question was how to automatically change the `pick` keyword to `reword` so that all commits would be edited. the answer was to set the sequence editor in `git config` to the command `sed -i s/pick/reword/`. This can be done for a single command using the `-c` switch:

```
git -c sequence.editor='sed -i s/pick/reword/' rebase -i <commit-id>
```

For the second part, of actually changing all the commit messages, it turns out that I do not need to worry about the first part. I just need to use the `-x` switch to execute a git command for each commit message to be edited. For this, instead of setting the sequence editor, the core editor needs to be set with `-c core.editor='<sed-command>'`:

```
git rebase <commit-id> -x "git -c core.editor='sed -i s/git-svn-id.*//g' commit --amend"
```

---

#### Additional Information for Preserving Committer Name, Email, & Date

**Edit:** The committer name, email, & date can be copied from author information for each commit with the following command:

```
git rebase <commit-id> -x "GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%ad)\" git -c user.name='$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%an)' -c user.email='$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%ae)' -c core.editor='sed -i s/git-svn-id.*//g' commit --amend"
```

**Edit:** The previous edit had an error in it. The committer date was not being set correctly. In order to use the correct date for each individual commit, add `` `cat .git/rebase-merge/orig-head` `` to the end of the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` command:

```
git rebase <commit-id> -x "GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%ad `cat .git/rebase-merge/orig-head`)\" git -c user.name='$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%an)' -c user.email='$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%ae)' -c core.editor='sed -i s/git-svn-id.*//g' commit --amend"
```

This will retrieve the date using the hash from the original commit instead of only using the date from the most recent commit.

**Edit:** I was having trouble preserving the committer date for each commit using the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variable with rebase. So after some playing around I was able to do what I wanted with `git cherry-pick`. This may not be the best method to achieve this, but it worked for me.

First I made a list of all commit hashes in reverse order (note that `<start-commit>` is not included:

```
git log --reverse --format="%H" <start-commit>...<end-commit> > ../hashes.txt
```

Then I used the following loop command to add each commit individually while preserving committer name, email, & date (if you do not need to modify commit message omit `-c core.editor='<editor-command>'` & add `--no-edit` option to commit command):

```
for COMMIT in $(cat ../hashes.txt); do \
  git cherry-pick $COMMIT && \
  GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log -1 --format=%cd $COMMIT)" git -c user.name="$(git log -1 --format=%cn $COMMIT)" -c user.email="$(git log -1 --format=%ce $COMMIT)" -c core.editor='sed -i s/git-svn-id.*//g' commit --amend; \
  if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then break; fi; done
```

The `if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then break; fi;` code forces the loop to exit if the cherry pick fails. If this occurs, you will need to remove all hashes from the `hashes.txt` file before you can continue. If it stops with a cherry pick in progress, you will need to resolve any conflicts then use `git cherry-pick continue`. Then you will need to amend the commit manually to set committer name, email, & date before continuing.